# Descargar tablas de mysql a excel Pero con varias hojas mysql y php

Tags: php, html, mysql

espero se encuentre muy bien.

Lo que sucede es que tengo una base de datos con varias tablas (en mysql), quiero descargar esas tablas a un archivo excel pero que cada una de esas tablas quede en una hoja del excel distinta, es una pagina web, estoy tabajando con html y php.

Alguien sabe como podria hacerlo.

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: No veo dificultad alguna en tu caso, que las tablas se descarguen en archivos separados solo tienes que abrir uno de ellos y luego importar el resto de archivos al libro abierto

Comment: Si usas phpmyadmin, hay un tab con el nombre "Export" o "Exportar" ahi estan las opciones para descargas las tablas a formato que puede ser leido por Excel (CSV por ejemplo)